# Why can some php settings can be changed in php.ini but not .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've noticed that certain settings like `display_errors` can be changed in .htaccess but others, like `allow_url_include`, cannot. I can change them in the php.ini file, but not in .htaccess.

Before I go further, yes I do want to change the url_include value and I realize that that is a huge security risk. It's not for a live site, though. This is all being done on my local apache server.

Anyway, other settings like `allow_url_fopen` and `enable_dl` can't be changed either, but they all have local values, separate from master values, in the phpinfo() output, so it certainly LOOKS like these things can be changed outside of the php.ini file.

Am I missing some setting in the php.ini file that allows certain things to be changed in .htaccess files? Is it something else completely? What controls this, and how can I change it?

PHP 5.5.14
Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) in case that's relevant.

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: it relates to processing order, by the time the server gets to the .htacess file to process the detectives a lot has already  happened.

Comment: Also, phpinfo wouldn't display nothing in local values column simply because it can't be set at runtime/per-directory. Local values would be populated by master values if master value is final level it can be configured. Unless you are seeing local values that are _different_ from master value, then you shouldn't assume that the local value can actually be set "locally"

Comment: @Anthony I haven't seen that page before, but I think it might help. Thanks.
Regarding phpinfo, I guess it just seems weird to me that certain settings in the core settings can only have a single value on all levels when other parts of phpinfo only have one column.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like `display_errors` are reasonably enabled/disabled by individual users. I might want to turn on errors on a dev page temporarily to test something out.

Stuff like `allow_url_include` are security restrictions, so letting individual users bypass it would defeat the purpose of those restrictions.

Comment: Yeah, I get the utility of making some settings more accessible than others. I'm wondering how a server determines that. The instructions to let something be changed in .htaccess but something else not must exist somewhere.

Comment: @Jorek They're compiled in the PHP source.